# Use Backbone or write a jQuery plugin for this...or both?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I'm sure this functionality already exists as a jQuery plugin.

Let's say I want to create a "transfer" control, like [this](http://www.ajaxblender.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/easy-multi-select-transfer-with-jquery.jpg). I have two text boxes, and I want to transfer data between the two via buttons.

I'm heavily using Backbone.js in my web application.

I could do this via a Backbone view + collections, or I could write a jQuery plugin to handle this. If I write a jQuery plugin, I would probably interface with it inside a Backbone view in order to modularize things.

Comment: Please say why you're down-voting questions if you decide to down-vote.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a pretty simple jQuery function:

```
$('.transfer').on('click',function(){
    $($(this).data('from'))
        .find(':selected')
        .remove()
        .appendTo($(this).data('to'))
        .prop('selected',false);
});
```

Assuming the following HTML:

```
<select id="one" multiple>
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
    <option>d</option>
</select>
<select id="two" multiple></select>

<button class="transfer" data-from="#one" data-to="#two">&raquo;</button>
<button class="transfer" data-from="#two" data-to="#one">&laquo;</button>
```

[**--- jsFiddle DEMO ---**](http://jsfiddle.net/jackwanders/GsZ9N/)

You could create a small jQuery plugin out of this, giving it two `select` elements and letting it create the transfer buttons and functionality, but it's also doable just as a function. With a plugin you could also add more complex functionality, like keeping the `option` elements in their original order as they're moved back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery-UI droppable: http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#propagation

On the drop event, you would want to look at the element dropped and do a Backbone .remove from the former collection and a .add to the receiving collection:

```
// Store a unique id of each item on the corresponding DOM element.
// ex. <div data-id="4129"></div>

$( ".selector" ).bind( "drop", function(event, ui) {
  // Look at the id and do a Collection.where() call to retrieve a reference to it.
  // Perform the .remove and the .add with that reference.
});
```